# "ERROR: File 'DIAWI_LINKS' does not exist" Jenkins Android

Tags: android, email, jenkins, diawi

[image: configuring diawi]

I have configured android project with jenkins all going good. 
I tried to use DIAWI api with jenkins it all works fine but I am not able to send diawi link in the email.

Email which I have received looks like below:

```
New Apk uploaded to diawi.com, here is the link
ERROR: File 'DIAWI_LINKS' does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states:

( for latest version 1.4, use ${FILE,path="filename.diawilink"} instead

Comment: not working for me. can you help me to resolve issue